# how can i copy and paste text from gvim into wordpress and word?

Tags: wordpress, vim

I have a file with 148 lines, when I input <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> it said that 148 lines yanked.

1. I open a word file, and right click, then select paste the yanked text into word.
   I find that only part of lines pasted into word, only the last 80 lines pasted.
2. I open my wordpress, the same 80 lines pasted into my blog.
   How  paste all the lines into my word and wordpress?

Comment: did you try pasting it in wordpress as a plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if vim has been compiled with access to system clipboard try this link

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/accessing-the-system-clipboard-from-vim/

Comment: i add the line in _vimrc, `set clipboard=unnamed`,it is ok.